# should common_msgs go in ros_ws or catkin_ws?

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Groovy -

If catkin_ws, where?

I tried to put common_msgs into the ros_ws (wstool set) but none of the packages inside the common_msgs stack build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62102/should-common_msgs-go-in-ros_ws-or-catkin_ws?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, common_msgs is a catkin repository. [Build it in a catkin workspace](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2